# How to initialize an array inside a dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary declared like this:

```
var myDict = [Int : [Int]]()
```

The array in it is not initialized, so every time I have to check it first:

```
if (myDict[idx] == nil) {
    myDict[idx] = []
}
```

How to initialize it as an empty array in `MyDict` declaration?

Comment: I believe that you just didn't bind a value to that key `idx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could be misunderstanding something pretty key - let's make sure:

The way the dictionary works, is not to have **one** array, but an array for **each key**.

Each value of 'idx' you request the array for returns a **different** array.

You can't expect it to return an empty array - a dictionary is *meant* to return a nil value for a key that hasn't been set. To do what you're trying, the following would probably do the trick:

```
myDict[idx] = myDict[idx] ?? []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it this way

```
myDict.forEach {
    (var dictElement) -> () in
    dictElement.1 = [Int]()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what dictionary do if you try to retrieve a key for which no value exists.
You can subclass Dictionary and override the subscript func to get what you want like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html). Or simply write an extension, or write a operator defination to use a different symbol.

> “You can also use subscript syntax to retrieve a value from the dictionary for a particular key. Because it is possible to request a key for which no value exists, a dictionary’s subscript returns an optional value of the dictionary’s value type. ”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1).” iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/cn/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?l=en&mt=11